# Rails 3.1 assets not loading properly in production for ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rubygems, asset-pipeline, activeadmin

I'm using [ActiveAdmin](http://activeadmin.info/) with Rails 3.1.  The only images (that I'm aware of) that this gem uses are sorting arrows in the header rows of tables.  In development, the CSS properly references these images:

```
table.index_table th.sortable a {
    background: url("/assets/active_admin/orderable.png") no-repeat 0 4px;
    padding-left: 13px;
}
```

In production, the CSS does not properly reference these images, resulting in a 404:

```
table.index_table th.sortable a {
    background: url("/images/active_admin/orderable.png") no-repeat 0 4px;
    padding-left: 13px;
}
```

Here is the relevant content from my Gemfile:

```
gem 'rails', '3.1.1'

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails', '~> 3.1.0'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.1.0'
  gem 'uglifier'
end

gem 'activeadmin', :git => 'git://github.com/gregbell/active_admin.git'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There ended up being an [issue submitted](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues/630) to the ActiveAdmin git repository for this.  The solution (for me) was to upgrade my sass-rails gem to 3.1.4.

```
gem 'rails', '3.1.1'

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails', '~> 3.1.4'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.1.0'
  gem 'uglifier'
end

gem 'activeadmin', :git => 'git://github.com/gregbell/active_admin.git'
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use image-url instead of url. In production Rails 3.1 sets a hash to all your images. Like that you can expire them easily after a deploy. This is a nice feature because the browser can cache the assets better like this. The code you should use:

```
table.index_table th.sortable a {
  background: image-url("active_admin/orderable.png") no-repeat 0 4px;
  padding-left: 13px;
}
```

Rails 3.1 puts digets in all the assets because this variable is set in production.rb

```
config.assets.digest = true
```

you can set that to false as well but i dont suggest it.

If you cant touch the css for active_admin than you have to upgrade active_admin to the latest version and try again.